# NGXS | Select after route returning old data

Tags: angular, routes, ngxs

I'm facing an issue with NGXS. I have an array of objects and I edited one of the objects by dispatching an action. 
Now when I click on reset button, I want to route to parent component and reset the state back to original so I kept a copy of the original object. 
But, the problem is that when I perform the select operation in parent component, it still returns the old object.

```
@Select(ItemState.getItems) ItemNGXS: Observable<ItemStateModel>;
```

What I could be doing wrong?

Reset button code:

```
 resetArray() {
    this._store.dispatch(new EditItem(this.originalItem))
      .subscribe(res => {
        this._route.navigate(['questionnaire']);
    });
  }
```

item.state.ts editItem method:

```
@Action(EditItem)
    edit({ getState, setState }: StateContext<ItemStateModel>, { payload }: EditItem) {
        const state = getState();
        const ItemList = [...state.items];
          const index = itemList.findIndex(item => item.Id === payload.Id);
          itemList[index] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload));
          setState({
            ...state,
            items: itemList
          });
   }
```

I have noticed that the getItems revert the state back to the old state (i.e.) before edit. I'm not sure why Selector reverting it to old state.

Comment: show me your selector, how you use `ItemNGXS` observable and your state model

Comment: I got this one fixed. I actually had one action before that somewhere, which was causing the issue. I removed it and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Add your solution as an answer.

Comment: I'll add it tomorrow as I don't have the code with me right now. The problem was that before the select, I had an action which was fetching the data and setting it in store. It got fixed the moment I moved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolve. It was a silly mistake at my end.

```
 resetArray() {
    this._store.dispatch(new EditItem(this.originalItem))
      .subscribe(res => {
        this._route.navigate(['questionnaire']);
    });
  }
```

After routing to a component, I was dispatching an action which was setting the state to old data. I moved the code to correct place and it got fixed.